# How to solve html page blinking with scroller?

Tags: html, css

My HTML page is blinking with a scroller. when `<p>` tag is not there, it is not occurring. How to stop and how to add move content?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>testing</title>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.mySlides {display: none;}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height:auto;
  width: auto;
  /*margin: 0 2px;*/
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="hinner">
        <img src="Logo.png" alt="alternatetext" width="136px" height="84px">
        <table class="hinnertext">
            <tr>
                <td style=" font-size: 14px; color:#139ea0; border-right-style: solid; border-width: 0.1em; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;"><span style="color:#139ea0; line-height: 20px;">Mon - Fri 8.30 AM - 5.00 PM </span><br><span style="color:#fff; inline-height:20px; ">Weekend Closed</span></td>
                <td style="width:350px; color:#139ea0; border-right-style: solid; border-width: 0.1em; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                    <div style="float:left;"> <img src="outline_local_phone_white_24dp.png"> </div>
                    <div><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">call us: </span> <br> 
                    <span style="font-size: 18px; inline-height:20px; "> <a style="color:#D4D4D4;" href="tel:+94 11 2676858">+94 11 2676858</a> <a style="color:#D4D4D4;" href="tel:+94 113642727">+94 113642727</a></span> </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="FEL-slideshow1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="FEL-slideshow2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="FEL-slideshow3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="FEL-slideshow4.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div>

<!-- this is the problem area  -->
<p>
hi
</p>


</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; 
    src: url(/font/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}


body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}
div{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.header{
    /* display: block; */
    background: #0a1940;
    /*height: 150px;
    width: 100%;*/
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
/*Styleing for inside of header - where company logo is*/
.hinner{
    max-width: 1140px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 35px 0;
}
.hinnertext{
    padding: 4px 0;
    float: right!important;
}
.hinnerdivider{
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Can anyone help ? This happens when the paragraph tag is included. When it is not there, webpage is not blinking and the scroller is not showing up. I have marked it with comment, where I have added the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Hi:) Why do you have CSS after the closing <html> tag?

Comment: Move everything after the `</html>` tag to inside the `<style>` tag

Comment: Thank you .

no CSS from external file. there is no CSS after <HTML> tag.